# Random iexplore crashes when debugging (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web application I am developing that seems to crash completely at random when clicking links on any page. When this happens, I'm told 'An unhandled win32 exception occured in iexplore.exe'. When I try to debug, it says one is already attached.

What could this be relating to? I know without code it will be hard, but this seems like a very strange error to occur at random.

Comment: Did you try it on a different browser?

Comment: You should be attaching to either the devserver that visual studio launches, or w3wp.exe, not directly to iexplore.exe

Comment: @slandau : "An unhandled win32 exception occured in iexplore.exe", so it's IE crashing, not the web application.

Comment: Try using the F12 Developer tools in IE 9 and make sure you watch for any errors that normally go unreported (browsers tend to swallow them).

Answer (score 0):

I have had this happen to me before and the problem usually had to do with styling on html elements that IE just couldn't handle. A good test would be to run the app in Mozilla and Chrome to see if they crash. For me, 4/5 times it had to do with the overflow attribute on a div. For some reason, ie is quirky when it comes to scrolling. To find it, after you have tested in the other browsers, start taking blocks out one piece at a time and see if you get the error. If you don't get the error, then the problem is in that block, otherwise put it back in and take the next block out. Keep going until you find it.